# Using borders cause wrong alignment with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with Bootstrap. Look at the image below for red lines.

[image]

`Jumbotron` is aligned little on right. It fits with image divs on header area. However, `borders` cause header area to look like they're wrongly margined. Correct look would be around -20px from left, and -20px from right, to fit on line with below.

I've tried many things but couldn't solve the issue.

How can I make it so the borders will correctly align with below? If using borders isn't a good idea, how can I replicate this by using other html/css tags?

Source: **using Bootstrap 3**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 header-news-section">
            <img src="{{ URL::to('TEST/haber.jpg') }}"class="img-rounded header-news-section-image pull-left" alt="Haber">

            <a href="#">
                {{ $a = rand(0, 99) }}
                @for($y = 0; $y <= $a; $y++)
                    {{ $y }}
                @endfor
            </a>
        </div>
        @endfor
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                 <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
........

.header-news-section {
    min-height: 60px;
    border-color: #EEEEEE #CCCCCC #CCCCCC #EEEEEE;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.header-news-section a {
    display: block;
}

img.header-news-section-image {
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

**Edit:** I've solved it by doing `<div class="row" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">`. Anyone knows why is it being caused in first place?

Comment: Doing "<div class="row" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">" solved the issue. Can anyone explain why is this causing in first place?

Comment: You should not touch the left and right margin properties of bootstrap's row and column classes. Your hack might work, but you are overriding the left and right margin as well.

Comment: There is a certain amount of px space dedicated to the left and right gutters of containers, panels, etc...I've found I sometimes need to do a hack fix, if I don't want any extra space left over.

Comment: @AminMeyghani; Feel free to suggest me a workaround then.

Comment: The background problem is that Bootstrap is designed to build layouts based on *columns & gutters* and you are trying to override gutters. I would consider using `.panel` components and stick to the native Bootstrap philosphy, mantaining gutters.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occurs because of the additional CSS class `header-news-section` on your first row with `margin-left: 0px;`. This overrides the original margin which is defined for column classes and therefore the news articles appear more left than your Jumbotron.

This is the relevant part at the [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/):

> Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative margin on .rows.

Just add another `div` inside the columns like this where you may apply custom styling:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="header-news-section">
        <img src="{{ URL::to('TEST/haber.jpg') }}"class="img-rounded header-news-section-image pull-left" alt="Haber">
        <a href="#"> {{ $a = rand(0, 99) }} @for($y = 0; $y <= $a; $y++) {{ $y }} @endfor</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Maybe you have to edit your CSS after this, but this is the correct way to use bootstrap.